# Error code says "float object is not callable" but I didn't call it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was working on code that printed out the surface area of a cylinder:

```
class Cylinder(object):

    def __init__(self,height=1,radius=1):
        self.height = height
        self.radius = radius

    def volume(self):
        return float(3.14159265359 *(radius**2) * height)

    def surface_area(self):
        return ((2 * 3.14159265359 (self.radius **2)) + (2 * 3.14159265359 * self.radius * self.height))
```

All of the code worked... Except the surface_area

```
height = 5
radius = 7
cy = Cylinder(height,radius)

cy.volume()
```

This block printed out:
    769.69020012955, which is correct.

This is where the error occurred:

```
cy.surface_area()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-116a6dc9a6c1> in <module>()
----> 1 cy.surface_area()

<ipython-input-139-66295086aec9> in surface_area(self)
      9 
     10     def surface_area(self):
---> 11         return ((2 * 3.14159265359 (self.radius **2)) + (2 * 3.14159265359 * self.radius * self.height))

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

​^This is the error, I was working in Python 2 and I can't figure out what the problem is. What is wrong with the code?- I also would like to know why it is saying 'float' is not callable when I didn't call it.

Comment: You did try to call it: `3.14159265359 (`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling a float value here:

```
3.14159265359 (self.radius **2)
```

Note that there is nothing between the float and the `(...)`. You probably wanted to multiply, so you are missing a `*` there:

```
return ((2 * 3.14159265359 * (self.radius **2)) + (2 * 3.14159265359 * self.radius * self.height))
```

You may want to use the [`math.pi` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pi) rather than typing it out each time:

```
from math import pi

# ...

return 2 * pi * (self.radius ** 2) + 2 * pi * self.radius * self.height
```

Comment: I am probably going to start using that from now on, that would save a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Replace `3.14159265359 (self.radius **2)` with `3.14159265359 * (self.radius **2)`. Or even better, import `math` and replace `3.14159265359` by `math.pi`. See [reference](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html) for `math` module.